# How to run Chrome/Firefox with disabled flash plugin from watir script?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

How to run Chrome/Firefox with disabled flash plugin from watir script?

If I disable flash in Chrome, next time when I execute watir-webdriver script Flash is enabled again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Firefox it is easy. Disable flash in your default profile (the one you normally use) and then start the browser like this:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => "default"
```

More information: http://watirwebdriver.com/firefox/

For Chrome I thought this would do it, but looks like I am doing something wrong, since flash is enabled:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => ["--disable-internal-flash"]
```

More information: http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/

Workaround is to run this every time you want Flash disabled in Chrome:

```
browser.goto "about:plugins"
browser.span(:text => "Flash").parent.parent.parent.a(:text => "Disable", :class => "disable-group-link").click
```

Comment: It should probably be `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-internal-flash]` for Chrome to work. Will check that out when return to work on monday. Thanks for your suggestions, you helped me very much.

Comment: `%w[--disable-internal-flash]` is exactly the same thing as `["--disable-internal-flash"]`.

Comment: I tried and it works fine with Firefox, but for Chrome I could not disable Flash plugin even with `Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-internal-flash --disable-bundled-ppapi-flash --disable-flash-sandbox]`.

Comment: @mihijs: same here, I was not able to disable flash in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash` switch. The one above did not work for me.