# Chrome switch "disable-internal-flash" does not disable Flash plugin

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

What could be the reason that Chrome switch "disable-internal-flash" does not actually disable Flash plugin?

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-internal-flash]
```

Is there something wrong with code above or it may be caused by bug in Watir-Webdriver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Chrome/Firefox with disabled flash plugin from watir script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636255/how-to-run-chrome-firefox-with-disabled-flash-plugin-from-watir-script)

Answer (score 0):

try --flash-disable-internal at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This command line switch disabled the Flash plugin in my Chrome 39.0

--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash

Found it in here:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-plugins-discovery