# Disabling flash in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, flash

One of our internal applications has a flash object on a page. I need to test one of the corner cases when there is no flash plugin available/installed in the browser: *neither the internal (pepperflash), nor the system-wide adobe flash player plugin*.

According to the [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) documentation page, there is a relevant command-line switch:

> `--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash` - Disables the bundled PPAPI version of Flash.

But, this would turn off only the pepperflash internal chrome plugin.

According to the [How to run Chrome/Firefox with disabled flash plugin from watir script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636255/how-to-run-chrome-firefox-with-disabled-flash-plugin-from-watir-script) thread, there is also `--disable-internal-flash` switch, but it is also relevant to the chrome's internal flash plugin.

[Browserstack's documentation](http://www.browserstack.com/automate/python#enable-disable-flash) suggests to follow the principle *"the guillotine is the best dandruff cure"* and to disable all plugins by using `--disable-plugins` switch:

> To disable Flash in Chrome, create a chromeOptions capability, and
>   pass the --disable-plugins argument to the capability.

Is there a way to disable all flash plugins without disabling all plugins in Chrome?

---

For instance, would be perfect to have a preference to list all of the plugins that needs to be turned off:

```
plugins.disabled: ['Adobe Flash Player', 'pepperflash']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, there is [an another switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-plugins-discovery) which tells chrome not to load external plugins at all:

> `--disable-plugins-discovery` Disable discovering third-party plug-ins. Effectively loading only ones shipped with the browser plus
>   third-party ones as specified by --extra-plugin-dir and --load-plugin
>   switches.

By combining `--disable-internal-flash` and `--disable-plugins-discovery` I've achieved disabling all flash plugins in Chrome.

Comment: would this switch work in the other way then to enable flash ?

Answer (score 2):

chrome://plugins doesn't exist anymore in Chrome 57 and above. Method proposed by alecxe in accepted answer unfortunately doesn't work for me.

I was able to workaround this issue by turning on mobile emulation on ChromeDriver. Example code for some languages can be found here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

Example code for java from the above page:

```java
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");

Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

You can also specify your own screen resolution, pixel ratio and even userAgent.

```java
Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<String, Object>();
deviceMetrics.put("width", 1920);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 1080);
deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 1.0);

Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19");

Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

This will work with RemoteWebDriver also.

Answer (score 1):

To disable Flash Player, type:

```
chrome:plugins
```

Into your URL bar. There you will see a list of all your plugins, including Flash Player. Press the button that says disable and you are good to go!

Comment: I need to disable flash plugins through selenium webdriver (command-line switch or chrome preferences aka options). Sorry for confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Adam! - you've actually made me look at the plugins page more closely and think about the problem from a different perspective.

Comment: No problem, and best of luck to you!